# ServiceKnownTypes Lists not working on WCF client when re-using assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a wcf service which has 3 methods, get a list of items, add items, and get a single item.

There are 4 possible types that are inherited from a base class. 
The service is decorated with ServiceKnownType for each of the derived classes.

When I consume the service and don't choose to re-use the assemblies and reference the pocos the getlist works as expected. When I do re-use the assemblies the list throws a serialization exception.

Looking at the reference.cs file generated by the wcf client I can see the KnownTypeAttribute is created on the base class that's been generated. On the project where I re-use the base classes it decorates the methods with the ServiceKnownTypeAttribute instead.

So on invoking the web method to return the list I get the following... 
*The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to 'TheChildObject' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.*

Is there a work around for this problem? Must be quite common?

Answer (score 1):

I add such a line above the relevant interfaces

```
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypesHelper))]
```

and the implementation of

```
public static class KnownTypesHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lists all WCF known types
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="provider"></param>
    /// <returns>A collection of all WCF known types</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Type> knownTypes =
            new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Type>();

        knownTypes.Add(typeof(WrntyCommon.WrntyDBEnums));

        // Add any types to include here.
        knownTypes.Add(typeof(AAA));
        knownTypes.Add(typeof(BBB));
        knownTypes.Add(typeof(CCC));

        return knownTypes;
    }

}
```

Comment: just adding the knowtypes attributes to the base class did the trick. I now have serviceknowtype on the service contract interface and knowntype on the base class, and it works in both scenarios